# How to get unique chat identifier in Amazon Connect CTR (Contact Trance Records)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chat, amazon-connect

I have integrated Amazon Connect Chat on my website. Whenever, a customer start chat, at the end of the chat Amazon Connect provides us with a CTR (Contact Trace Record). I want to get a unique identifier of the chat in the CTR. CTR provides ContactID but that's not something that I am looking for. I am looking for some unique identifier through which I can recognize the repeated customer.

In the case of Amazon Connect voice call, there is a unique identifier in the form of phone number through which I can recognize the repeated customer. I am looking for the same kind thing but for chat, it could be any kind of token. But, at this point, I don't have any idea how to set up this?

I also try to use [StartChatContact API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_StartChatContact.html) of Amazon Connect but don't know how to get the intended results from this api.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Connect provides this functionality in a service called [Customer Profiles](https://aws.amazon.com/connect/customer-profiles/). Have a look in the section “Automated customer profile matching”. I think this is what you are looking for.